# Bean validation after setter?

Tags: bean-validation

I want to validate the trimmed string length, like:

```
@Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "Please enter a valid username (5-20 characters)")
String userName;
```

Given user name `foo` (6 chars), it will be trimmed to `foo` (3 chars) in the setter method, however, validate against the raw input seems a bit of useless.

Comment: btw, you may use `{min}` and `{max}` placeholders in error message to get rid of hardcoded values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of altering the validation procedure, you could write your own constraint which wraps the expected validation logic.

I have found such an implementation of a `@TrimmedSize` annotation at the [auto-trader-spring-spike](http://code.google.com/p/auto-trader-spring-spike/source/browse/trunk/SpikesProject/src/main/java/com/autotrader/frameworks/TrimmedSize.java?r=8) project:

```
package com.autotrader.frameworks;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TrimmedSizeValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrimmedSize {
    String message() default "size too small";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    int min() default 0;

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And the validator:

```
package com.autotrader.frameworks;


import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class TrimmedSizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<TrimmedSize, String> {

    private int length;

    public void initialize(TrimmedSize trimmedSize) {
        length = trimmedSize.min();
    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return value.trim().length() >= length;
    }
}
```

It uses an Apache License 2.0, but even then you could write this code from scratch once you've seen it.